# Push contacts to Google from local

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, contacts

I am able to synchronize Thunderbird with my gmail contacts such that I can use all of my gmail contacts in Thunderbird.

I have made changes locally to my contacts locally in Thunderbird. How can I export those changes to my gmail contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the [Google Contacts add-on for Thunderbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/7307)

[image]

> **Access bi-directionaly to Google
>   contacts** via address books. This
>   extension detects gmail accounts which
>   have already set up and creates
>   address books for each of them. Cards
>   in the address books are synchronized
>   with Google contacts; they represent
>   the current Google contacts contents
>   and Google contacts will be modified
>   when you modify the cards. TB's
>   mailing lists and Google's contacts
>   groups are synchronized in the same
>   manner.

For more information, [click this link.](http://outgoing.mozilla.org/v1/886311bbe8084acb8b282768625bd1757db72991/http%3A//hogiblog.blogspot.com/2008/05/synchronizing-google-contacts-and.html)